# Python - reading a single file, extracting data from it, and then writing it to many files

Tags: python, loops, parsing, file-writing

I am trying to read 1 file, parse data from it then write each parsed column to another file in a different directory. Here is my code:

```
os.makedirs("new_directory")
my_file = open("original_file.txt", "r+")
output = "new_file.txt"
outputfile = open("new_directory/"+output, "w")
num = 3

for line in my_file:
    line = line.split("\t")
    sample = line[num]
    lst = line[1] + "\t" + line[2] + "\t" + sample + "\n"
    outputfile.write(lst)
```

This is as far as I have got. I want to write multipe output files with different information from the original file, and save them all in the new directory. How can I write a loop to change the output file name each time - I was trying to increment 'num' and then maybe add it to the output variable:

```
output = "new_file" + num + ".txt"
outputfile = open("new_directory/"+output, "w")
```

Or something like this. Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you give an example of how the data is? Thanks.

Comment: 'chr    pos    gene    ID_1    ID_2    ID_3    ID_4'
      '1      123     p53      121      763      767    200'
      '2      124     rtk1      162      323       123    72'
     ' 3      156     tf1        127       34        45      764'

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of files

```
outputfiles = []    
for num in range(number_of_output_files):     
    output = "new_file" + str(num) + ".txt" # or "new_file%d.txt"%(num)
    outputfiles.append( open("new_directory/"+output, "w") )

for num in range(number_of_output_files):     
    outputfiles[num].write( 'something\n' )

for num in range(number_of_output_files):     
    outputfiles[num].close()
```

Comment: Thanks. But I get an error message: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects at the 'output = "new_file" + num + ".txt" line

Comment: use `output = "new_file" + str(num) + ".txt"`

Comment: This is why i much prefer `.format()` - no issues with `str and int concatenation` and no issues with `%d` vs `%s`. Just a simple `output = "new_file{}.txt".format(num)`